# httpd document root does not exists

Tags: apache-2.2

I set up a virtual host on my apache server and after restarting the server, it gives the warning: **Starting httpd: Warning: DocumentRoot /www/html/platinum does not exist**

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
DocumentRoot /www/html/platinum
ServerName www.platinum.com
ErrorLog logs/platinum.com-error_log
CustomLog logs/platinum.com-access_log common
```

can any one would help me to sort this out

Comment: Well, does `/www/html/platinum` exist? Does the Apache user have access to it?

Comment: yes the directory exists and selenix is disabled on my system.system permission is already give to the directory.would u tell me how to set up Apache user access to that .

Comment: What user is Apache running as? What's the output of running "ls -l /www/html/platinum" as that user?

Comment: when runs command : ls: cannot access /www/html/platinum: No such file or directory and apache log for user is as follow -D AP_DOC_ROOT="/var/www"
 -D AP_GID_MIN=100
 -D AP_HTTPD_USER="apache"
 -D AP_LOG_EXEC="/var/log/httpd/suexec.log"
 -D AP_SAFE_PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"
 -D AP_UID_MIN=500
 -D AP_USERDIR_SUFFIX="public_html"

Comment: Your folder does not exist, see first comment.

Comment: no dude it's already there. i am working on cent os 6 sysem any idea?

Comment: Please do a `tree` command and share the output, something is defo wrong.

Comment: @ luastoned oops its says bash: tree: command not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that, there is no dir  named platinum in the /www/html/. So, first create the dir platinum  in /www/html/ and set the user and group of the apache to the  created folder.

Comment: yes, I managed to settle the things. thnks :)